# How to extract yahoo-finance analyst price targets by VBA?

Tags: vba, web-scraping, yahoo-finance

I am trying to extract yahoo-finance analyst price targets by VBA(eg: no. of analyst, high, low, average, current)

[image]

but I can't extract any of these by .getelementsbyclassname/.getelementbyID.

Here is my code:

```
Sub Analysis_import()

Dim website As String

Dim request As Object

Dim response As String

Dim html As New HTMLDocument

Dim price As Variant

website = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/analysis?p=AAPL"

Set request = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

request.Open "get", website, False

request.setRequestHeader "If-Modified-since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"

request.send

response = StrConv(request.responseBody, vbUnicode)

html.body.innerHTML = response

price = html.getElementsByClassName("Fz(m) D(ib) Td(inh)").innerText

Debug.Print price

End Sub
```

What is the problem? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fields you wish to grab from that site generate dynamically, hence you can't fetch them using `HTMLDocument` parser. If you want to locate the fields using `tag`, `id` ,`class` e.t.c, your options would be `IE` or `Selenium`.

However, the good news is the required fields are available in some script tag within raw json content. So, you can process them using [vba json converter](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON) or regex even when you stick with `xmlhttp` requests. The following script is based on regex.

```
Sub GrabAnalysisInfo()
    Const Url As String = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/analysis?p=AAPL"
    Dim sResp$, sHigh$, currentPrice$
    Dim analystNum$, sLow$, tMeanprice$

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", Url, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36"
        .send
        sResp = .responseText
    End With

    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Pattern = "numberOfAnalystOpinions[\s\S]+?raw"":(.*?),"
        If .Execute(sResp).count > 0 Then
            analystNum = .Execute(sResp)(0).SubMatches(0)
        End If

        .Pattern = "targetMeanPrice[\s\S]+?raw"":(.*?),"
        If .Execute(sResp).count > 0 Then
            tMeanprice = .Execute(sResp)(0).SubMatches(0)
        End If

        .Pattern = "targetHighPrice[\s\S]+?raw"":(.*?),"
        If .Execute(sResp).count > 0 Then
            sHigh = .Execute(sResp)(0).SubMatches(0)
        End If

        .Pattern = "targetLowPrice[\s\S]+?raw"":(.*?),"
        If .Execute(sResp).count > 0 Then
            sLow = .Execute(sResp)(0).SubMatches(0)
        End If

        .Pattern = "currentPrice[\s\S]+?raw"":(.*?),"
        If .Execute(sResp).count > 0 Then
            currentPrice = .Execute(sResp)(0).SubMatches(0)
        End If
    End With

    Debug.Print analystNum, tMeanprice, sHigh, sLow, currentPrice
End Sub
```

Comment: Was there a partic reason for choosing `If .Execute(sResp).count > 0` over `.test` as I would imagine the latter to be slightly faster.

Comment: Hi @QHarr, I used `.count` property because I thought it would help the script avoid indexerror in case any desired field is missing. I'm not familiar with the one you suggested by the way.

Comment: I think `.test` is faster and this case you are only ever taking the first match. However, the speed difference is probably negligible in this small number of access cases. I don't, however, have a citation for that. It is based on the assumption of less overhead in simply testing for presence rather than how many times present.

Comment: Thank you for your help again. The code was functionable until today. The error message "Access is denied" pops up. What can I do?